# Huggingface: How do I find the max length of a model?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-tokenizers

Given a transformer model on huggingface, how do I find the maximum input sequence length?

For example, here I want to truncate to the max_length of the model: `tokenizer(examples["text"], padding="max_length", truncation=True)` How do I find the value of "max_length"?

I need to know because I am trying to solve this error "Asking to pad to max_length but no maximum length is provided and the model has no predefined maximum length. Default to no padding."

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps late, but if you haven't found a solution, I think you can use the tokenizer of that model.
For instance:

```
>>> MODEL = "google/flan-t5-xl"
>>> tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL)
>>> tokenizer.model_max_length
512

>>> MODEL = "facebook/bart-base"
>>> tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL)
>>> tokenizer.model_max_length
1024
```

Comment: I found this did not always reliably work. `model_max_length` sometimes seemed to be `1000000000000000019884624838656` ... What worked for me was accessing the model config, e.g., `model.config.max_position_embeddings`! (This also works with pipelines, just use `mypipe.model.config.max_position_embeddings` which is important if you feed your `mypipe` any text and need to add `truncation` and `max_length` so that no RuntimeErrors will occur.)

Comment: Yep, that's also a way to determine the model input length, but again  not always working. The `max_position_embeddings` actually comes from the config.json file (in the model card, go to the `Files and versions` tab). Sometimes, that field is just missing, for example https://huggingface.co/gpt2/blob/main/config.json.

Comment: Great ... I forgot that different model architectures save such information in different fields. Now I even remember that I noticed this in the past (around the huggingface 2.* version) but forgot about it. But I would assume that this _maximum sequence length_ information is always stored in the `config.json` just using different keys as it is integral for the model setup. This just means more conditional logic for extraction. And maybe some heuristic for plausible value ranges. (For GPT2 the keys might be `n_ctx` or `n_positions` ...) I thought there was a property that allowed easier access

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, no standard on which key specifies the max length of a model in model config (config.json). you need to know the "group" of the model, and do it case by case.

eg. for llama-like models, use "max_position_embeddings". and for baichuan, you should pick "model_max_length". for chatglm, "seq_length" ...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose BertTokenizer, we have:

`tokenizer=BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_path)`

`print(tokenizer.max_model_input_sizes)`
The above code will give you a dictionary of all the Bert model checkpoints with their 'max_length'